# Multi-row SQL Select Query

Tags: sql, select

I need some SQL which returns any rows for a given user where multiple rows exist but none of them have `primary_bran = 1`

```
user_id dest_id bran    primary_bran    act  action_pri
  695      0    ZTZ           0          1       0
  695      0    ZUA           0          1       0
  695      0    ZUD           0          1       0
  695      0    ZUS           0          1       0
  695      0    ZUT           0          1       0
  695      0    ZUV           0          1       0
  695      0    ZVB           0          1       0
  695      0    ZVC           0          1       0
  695      0    ZVJ           0          1       0
  695      0    ZVK           0          1       0
  695      0    ZWU           0          1       0
  695      0    ZWV           0          1       0
  695      0    ZWX           0          1       0
  695      0    ZXB           0          1       0
  695      0    ZYK           0          1       0
  695      0    ZYL           0          1       0
  695      0    ZYN           0          1       0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the sub-query to disqualify users how has a row with primary_bran = 1.

```
select * from table t1
where not exists (select 1 from table
                  where user_id = t1.user_id
                  and primary_bran = 1)
```

If only users with at least 2 rows are supposed to be returned, also add a count condition:

```
select * from table t1
where not exists (select 1 from table
                  where user_id = t1.user_id
                  and primary_bran = 1)
  and (select count(*) from table
       where user_id = t1.user_id) >= 2
```

Comment: And where does the "multiple rows" part go?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to list out all rows for given user who contains multiple `primary_bran <> 1` records.

```
WITH WithRecordsCount AS 
(
    SELECT *, COUNT(user_id) OVER(PARTITION BY user_id) AS CNT
    FROM yourtable
    WHERE primary_bran <> 1 OR primary_bran IS NULL
)
SELECT * FROM WithRecordsCount WHERE CNT > 1
```